# Java - resetting with if statement

Tags: java, eclipse, math, if-statement, minecraft

I want to change R back to 0 but for some reason it won't do it.

```
    protected void addPotionEffects(ItemStack item, World world, EntityPlayer player)
{
    {
    if (R == 3) {
        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(potionEffect[0], potionDuration[0] * 20, potionTier[0]));
        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(potionEffect[1], potionDuration[1] * 20, potionTier[1]));
        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(potionEffect[2], potionDuration[2] * 20, potionTier[2]));
        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(potionEffect[3], potionDuration[3] * 20, potionTier[3]));
        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(potionEffect[4], potionDuration[4] * 20, potionTier[4]));
        R = 0;
    } else {
        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(potionEffect[1], potionDuration[1] * 20, potionTier[1]));
        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(potionEffect[2], potionDuration[2] * 20, potionTier[2]));
        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(potionEffect[3], potionDuration[3] * 20, potionTier[3]));
        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(potionEffect[4], potionDuration[4] * 20, potionTier[4]));
    }
    return;
    }
}
```

I'm a **beginner** with Java and this script is for Minecraft.
I can't lose potionEffect[0] in-game when I drink milk or wait until the `potionDuration[0]` is done.

By the way `R = 0` and get `R = Math.abs(R+1);` every time the potion get consumed.
I get no error's in the script or else where.

Here is the **whole script**: [pastebin.com/ciaLjXZH](http://pastebin.com/ciaLjXZH)

So what do I do to fix this?

Comment: where do you declare R?

Comment: May be `R` is always not `3`?

Comment: @cremersstijn At `public class Item extends ItemFood` as `private static int R = 0;`

Comment: @Octopus Read my post again

Comment: Can you post the code where R is declared and all the relevant code?

Comment: Why is `R` static? any use case?

Comment: Probably wont fix your issue, but I've rewritten the method to remove code duplication and the remove unnecessary brakctes [it's here](http://pastebin.com/GvScMUHu)

Comment: @Octopus Like I said before I'm a beginner so...

Comment: @DanTemple It didn't fix it indeed but still thanks

Comment: Please remove the static modifier and check

Comment: @Octopus Nope that didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

I had:

```
private int R1 = 0;
private int R2 = 0;
```

But it needed to be:

```
public int R1 = 0;
public int R2 = 0;
```

Thanks for all the help